# setting focus by clicking on element but excluding some children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to focus element .editor on every click on .step. The problem is that I would like exclude clicking on on the buttons: .new, .delete, .copy, .resize. If i click on buttons, i am not focusing, just executing others functions setting in separately. How can I do this.
This is html structure:

```
<div class="step">
 <div class="editor"></div>
   <div class="new"></div>
   <div class="delete"></div>
   <div class="copy"></div>
   <div class="resize"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my wrong jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.step', function() {
    if ( $(this)  !== $(".sort-slides") || $(".draggable_on") || $(".copy-slide") || $(".new-slide") || $(".delete-slide")  )
    $(this).find(".editor").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when an event fires on an element, it's triggered on each of the element's ancestors. This is called *event propagation*. It's possible to stop this behavior by returning `false` from your event handler.

```
$(".new, .delete, .copy, .resize").click(function(event) {

  // do something
  alert("click");

  // prevent the event from propagating
  return false;
});

$(".step").click(function() {

  // do something
  alert("focus");
});
```

Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ionzk) on CodePen.

However, as Gupta said, the `focus` function is only applicable to `<input>`, `<select>` and `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your if statement is not correct.

```
if (x == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5) { ... }
```

is NOT the same as

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) { ... }
```

The statement will always return true, since anything apart from 0 will be truthy. So even if x would be 0, the statement would be

```
if (false || true || true || true || true) { ... }
```

Furthermore, `$(this)` will always be the `.step` div catching the click event, and not any of it's children.